# Chrome Extension - Passing URL from popup.js to Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I am using `chrome.tabs.query` to get the current active URL, and then I want to pass it to my backend in firebase. In the following code:

```
function geturl() {
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
  var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tabURL; //The line I changed to pass the URL to html.
   });

  fbase.set({
    title: tabURL,      // If I set this to title: "test", it works
  });

}
```

Now when I trigger this, nothing happens, so I checked and filled in test, which does work. This makes me think Chrome does not want me to do that. I can pass the URL to my `popup.html`, which does show it, but can't send it out from the `popup.js`. Is there a workaround for this, or do I need to work with the `popup.html`?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `chrome.tabs.query` is asynchronous.

`fbase.set` is called, while `chrome.tabs.query`  is not finished executing.

You must put `fbase.set` inside the callback of `chrome.tabs.query`.

```
function getUrl() {

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {

        var tabURL = tabs[0].url;

        fbase.set({title: tabURL});
    });
}
```

[Asynchronous vs. synchronous methods](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#apis)